# Editing already up-loaded images

Tags: images

I am fairly new at using wordpress and have been working on a blog for quite a while.. These past few days I have been uploading pictures - which I have finally managed to do however, I find that the size of some are too big, some I want to crop and others - just turn.

Meanwhile, I must be doing something wrong?
When selecting media, library - the images appear. When selecting an image, it seems that I should be able to edit it by selecting the edit button underneath the picture. However, when selecting "edit", a page comes up where the image does not appear. Instead the header appears and 3 areas, - Alternative text, Caption and Description. As far as I understand from various help pages, the picture should appear when selecting "edit" in addition to a variety of editing possibilities as cropping etc.

What am I doing wrong? Does it have anything to do with me having uploaded the pictures via my Wordpress app on the phone? I don't see how this should affect the tools on wordpress on my laptop and in anycase - the pictures are there in the library. I just can not edit them.

I hope you can help. With thanks!

Comment: Juuust in case, have you tried disabling your adblocker for that site/page? Or can you open the Dev Tools (F12 on windows) and check the Console and Network tabs. I guess you are not familiar with it so here is a link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network . This could help us see what might be wrong with it

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested but it seems there are no adblockers. However, I did find some old pictures that I had uploaded ages ago but not posted (as I wasn't ready), that I had compressed in order to upload them via the wordpress app - and it seems that I can edit these. So...I wonder if it could be that the newly uploaded pics are too big - which however is interesting, as it was no problem moving uploading them from my photo album on my phone to wordpress via the wordpress app. But interestingly, the pictures do not appear as thumbnails on the media ...only

Comment: ..only as a file. When selecting the file, however, the image shows. Selecting "edit image" will then take me to a page again, where I no longer see the image and as described above. To me this is very confusing. But now I will try to downsize all images before uploading them... - thanks again!!